# Files.walkFileTree vs Files.walk performance on Windows NTFS

Tags: java, ntfs

[My application](https://komga.org/) needs to periodically scan filesystems in order to process files. Initially I was using `java.nio.file.Files.walk` to perform the scan, but soon enough I encountered an issue with some `AccessDeniedException`. [Found out](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-May/041424.html) after some googling that `Files.walk` expects the explored directory tree to be accessible by the user, else it would crash and stop, which renders this function unusable for my application (it is self-hosted by a multitude of people on various kind of systems).

I changed the implementation to use `java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree` instead, which seemed to work great and handled the `AccessDeniedException` in the user code.

However, someone recently reported that scanning time skyrocketed **from a mere 12 seconds** (using `Files.walk`) **to 80 minutes** (using `Files.walkFileTree`)! The user has around 10,000 folders and 120,000 files. It is running Windows, and the disk is using NTFS. Other users with similar number of folders/files but running Linux experience scan times under 10s, whatever the method used.

I am trying to understand what could cause the massive performance hit by using `Files.walkFileTree` on Windows with NTFS, but given I don't have access to a test system running Windows, I can't debug the code to understand where the time is spent.

Would you know if there are know issues around walking a file tree under Windows NTFS? And if there are some other methods I could use to perform that task? Keeping in mind that I need to handle `AccessDeniedException` in user code.

Comment: I use `Files.walkFileTree` for all tree scans, it does around 120,000 files in 5-10 seconds on my slow PC (SSD) and 6-12 seconds for similar content on NAS drive. You can introduce performance problems if your callbacks or predicates make heavy use of file/io or make decisions using File.XXX() calls instead of accessing the provided BasicFileAttributes `attr.xxx()`.

Comment: Oh, wow @DuncG that improves my applications runtime from 70 minutes to 14 minutes. Did not realise `Files.size`, `Files.lastModified` etc. were making the same `Files.readAttributes` call. Even better - `Files.walkFileTree` provides the `BasicFileAttributes` in the `visitFile` call.