# Listing all files that matches the regular expression recursively

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to load all files that matches the path or regular expression.

If the path is

`"C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\src\test\resources\screenshots/*/*.png"`

it should find all screenshots in "screenshots" folder. If the path is

`C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\src\test\resources\screenshots/first.png`

it should find only the one file.

I was trying to list all files that match the criteria using:

```
File dir = new File("/");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(absolutePath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

but this is not recursive and finds files only in home folder.

I tried to also use Spring way:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
return resolver.getResources(pattern);
```

But this expects only relative paths and looking for files in classpath.

What is the correct, standard and pretty way how to do this?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli no, there is nothing about regexps in there..

Comment: Sure it is! Files.walk gives you a stream of files and then you can filter howerver you like Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(<you're regex here>)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Files.walk however ends when there is an exception, like AccessDenied. Isnt it also super non efficent? It seems it just literally traverse everything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542005/files-walkfiletree-vs-files-walk-performance-on-windows-ntfs

Comment: @SimonMartinelli there is still problem with access denied exception if it meets some folder it has no access to

Answer (score -1):

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
   .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
   .filter(p ->p.toString().matches(".*\\.png$"))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Passing your screenshots folder path as a `String` ('path') to the above will filter for you

Comment: this still throws AccessDenied exception if there is some folder it does not have access to on the way. + the regexp can be present anywhere in the path,..

Comment: Not sure if that's filterable. Shall check – though it begs the question: "Why, in your own screenshots tree, would there be files to which you don't have access?"

Comment: that tree was just an example, the path can be literally anything user wants it to be

Comment: You need to go for the 'long version' of recursing the fs to be able to cope with errors probably